# Dragable rows among multiple grids in AG Grid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am creating a task management page where there can be multiple ag-grid tables. I want to achieve a functionality, where i can drag rows among all those grids. I was follwoing example of ag-grid documentation, and i can drag rows among two grids, but not more then that. Is there a way, where i can drag and drop rows among more then two rows dynamically, considering user can create his own grids.

Right now in my code i am creating two states, leftApi, and rightApi, and storing data among them. As per documentation, i was able to make data sharing among two rows work by giving grid 1 leftApi, and other rightApi. But what if i do not want to define these states and manage data sharing in a way that allows me to dynamically share among more then 2 rows:

```
const Agtable = () => {
  const color = ["#00c875", "#fdab3d", "#e2445c", "#c4c4c4"];
  const [leftApi, setLeftApi] = useState(null);
  const [rightApi, setRightApi] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [completedData, setCompletedData] = useState([]);
  const [radioChecked, setRadioChecked] = useState(0);
  const [loadingRows, setLoadingRows] = useState([]);
  const [agGridApi, setAgGridApi] = useState(null);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      editable: (params) => params.data.id !== "aggrigate-data",
      enableRowGroup: true,
      enablePivot: true,
      enableValue: true,
      sortable: true,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true,
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 100,
    };
  }, []);

  // Date formating
  class DatePicker {
    // gets called once before the renderer is used
    init(params) {
      // create the cell
      this.eInput = document.createElement("input");
      this.eInput.value = params.value;
      this.eInput.classList.add("ag-input");
      this.eInput.style.height = "var(--ag-row-height)";
      this.eInput.style.fontSize = "calc(var(--ag-font-size) + 1px)";

      // https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
      $(this.eInput).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: () => {
          this.eInput.focus();
        },
      });
    }

    // gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
    getGui() {
      return this.eInput;
    }

    // focus and select can be done after the gui is attached
    afterGuiAttached() {
      this.eInput.focus();
      this.eInput.select();
    }

    // returns the new value after editing
    getValue() {
      return this.eInput.value;
    }

    // any cleanup we need to be done here
    destroy() {
      // but this example is simple, no cleanup, we could
      // even leave this method out as it's optional
    }

    // if true, then this editor will appear in a popup
    isPopup() {
      // and we could leave this method out also, false is the default
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Date formater
  const formatDate = (dateString) => {
    const [day, month, year] = dateString.split("/").map(Number);
    const formattedDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // Month is 0-indexed
    return formattedDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "2-digit",
      day: "2-digit",
    });
  };

  const parseDate = (dateString) => {
    const [day, month, year] = dateString.split("/");
    return new Date(`${month}/${day}/${year}`);
  };

  const fullDateToString = (inputDateString) => {
    const inputDate = new Date(inputDateString);

    const day = inputDate.getDate();
    const month = inputDate.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero-based
    const year = inputDate.getFullYear();

    // Pad the day and month with leading zeros if needed
    const formattedDay = day < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;
    const formattedMonth = month < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;

    return `${formattedDay}/${formattedMonth}/${year}`;
  };

  const convertDate = (date) => {
    const dateStr = date;
    const dateArray = dateStr.split("/");
    const day = dateArray[0];
    return day;
  };

  const convertMonth = (date) => {
    const dateStr = date;
    const dateArray = dateStr.split("/");
    const monthNumber = parseInt(dateArray[1], 10);
    const monthNames = [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
    ];
    const month = monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    return month;
  };

  //--------------------------------------

  // On ready table state
  const gridReady = (params, side) => {
    if (side === 0) {
      setLeftApi(params.api);
    }

    if (side === 1) {
      setRightApi(params.api);
    }
    var columnState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myColumnState"));
    if (columnState) {
      params.columnApi.applyColumnState({
        state: columnState,
        applyOrder: true,
      });
    }
  };

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setAgGridApi(params.api);
    // Call the function on grid ready
    gridReady(params);
  };

  const getTableData = async () => {
    const response = await getAllItems();
    const responseC = await getCompletedAllItems();
    const newData = response.map((res, i) => ({
      id: res.id,
      project: res.project,
      owner: res.owner,
      status: res.status,
      due_date: res.due_date,
      budget: "$" + res.budget,
      files: res.files, // Updated line
      timeline: res.timeline,
      last_updated: res.last_updated,
    }));
    const newDataC = responseC.map((res, i) => ({
      id: res.id,
      project: res.project,
      owner: res.owner,
      status: res.status,
      due_date: res.due_date,
      budget: "$" + res.budget,
      files: res.files, // Updated line
      timeline: res.timeline,
      last_updated: res.last_updated,
    }));
    setData([...newData, aggregatedDataRow]);
    setCompletedData([...newDataC, aggregatedDataRow]);
  };

  // Row drag persistence
  const onRowDragEnd = async (params, id) => {
    // Perform any additional actions after the swap operation
    console.log("Params : ", params);
    if (currentId !== id) {
      const rows = [];
      params.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((node) => rows.push(node.data));
      if (id === 1) {
        await deleteItem(params.node.data.id);
        await addCompletedItem({
          ...params.node.data,
          id: uuidv4(),
          budget: params.node.data.budget.replace("$", ""),
        });
        getTableData();
      }
      if (id === 0) {
        await deleteCompletedItem(params.node.data.id);
        await addItem({
          ...params.node.data,
          id: uuidv4(),
          budget: params.node.data.budget.replace("$", ""),
        });
        getTableData();
      }
    } else {
      const rows = [];
      params.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((node) => rows.push(node.data));
      // const newData = rows.filter((row) => row.id !== "aggrigate-data");
      localStorage.setItem("rowData", JSON.stringify(rows));
      console.log(
        "Rows : ",
        rows.filter((row) => row.id !== "aggrigate-data")
      );
    }
  };

  // Persist column swap state for table

  const swapColumnState = async (e) => {
    var columnState = JSON.stringify(e.columnApi.getColumnState());
    localStorage.setItem("myColumnState", columnState);
  };

  // Aggrigated row definition
  const aggregatedDataRow = {
    id: "aggrigate-data",
    project: "",
    owner: "", // You can customize this based on your needs
    status: "", // Customize based on your needs
    due_date: "",
    budget: "", // Implement your logic to calculate total budget
    files: [],
    timeline: { start_time: "", end_time: "" },
    last_updated: "",
    aggregatedData: true,
  };
  //--------------------------------------

  // Value edit
  const handleCellValueChanged = async (params, id) => {
    if (id === 0) {
      await updateItem(params.data.id, params.data);
    } else if (id === 1) {
      await updateCompletedItem(params.data.id, params.data);
    }
    getTableData();
  };
  //---------------------------------------------------

  // Keyboard enter
  const handleKeyDown = async (event, id) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      const newItem = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        project: user,
        owner: "info@yourmail.com",
        status: "Not Started",
        due_date: "28/11/2023",
        budget: "11000",
        files: [],
        timeline: { start_time: "25/11/2023", end_time: "28/11/2023" },
        last_updated: {
          update_time: "23/11/2023",
          updated_by: "info@yourmail.com",
        },
      };
      if (id === 0) {
        await addItem(newItem); // API call to add new item
      } else if (id === 1) {
        await addCompletedItem(newItem);
      }
      getTableData();
    }
  };

  // File Change
  const handleFileChanged = async (fileData, id, params) => {
    if (params.api.gos.gridOptions.gridId === 0) {
      const res = await getItemById(id);
      const item = { ...res, files: [...res.files, fileData[0]] };
      await updateItem(id, item);
    } else if (params.api.gos.gridOptions.gridId === 1) {
      const res = await getCompletedItemById(id);
      const item = { ...res, files: [...res.files, fileData[0]] };
      await updateCompletedItem(id, item);
    }
    getTableData();
  };
  //--------------------------------------

  // Timeline and fileicons
  class TimelineRangeEditor {
    init(params) {
      this.params = params;
      const { timeline } = params.data;
      const startDate = new Date(parseDate(timeline.start_time));
      const endDate = new Date(parseDate(timeline.end_time));

      this.container = document.createElement("div");
      this.container.style =
        "position: absolute; width: 250px; height: 100px; background-color: white; z-index: 9999;";

      this.flatpickr = flatpickr(this.container, {
        mode: "range",
        defaultDate: [startDate, endDate],
        onChange: async (selectedDates) => {
          const [newStartDate, newEndDate] = selectedDates;
          timeline.start_time = fullDateToString(newStartDate);
          timeline.end_time = fullDateToString(newEndDate);
          // Check if newEndDate is selected
          if (selectedDates.length === 2) {
            // Make an API call to update row data
            if (params.api.gos.gridOptions.gridId === 0) {
              await updateItem(this.params.data.id, {
                ...this.params.data,
                timeline: timeline,
              });
            } else if (params.api.gos.gridOptions.gridId === 1) {
              await updateCompletedItem(this.params.data.id, {
                ...this.params.data,
                timeline: timeline,
              });
            }
            getTableData();
            // Close the Flatpickr instance
            this.flatpickr.close();
          }
        },
      });

      document.body.appendChild(this.container);
    }

    getGui() {
      return this.container;
    }

    afterGuiAttached() {
      this.flatpickr.open(); // Commented to prevent automatic opening
    }

    getValue() {
      return { timeline: this.params.data.timeline };
    }

    destroy() {
      this.container.parentNode.removeChild(this.container);
    }
  }

  const renderTimeline = (data) => {
    const startDay = convertDate(data.start_time);
    const endDay = convertDate(data.end_time);
    const startMonth = convertMonth(data.start_time);
    const endMonth = convertMonth(data.end_time);

    if (startMonth === endMonth) {
      return `${startDay}-${endDay} ${startMonth}`;
    } else {
      return `${startDay} ${startMonth}-${endDay} ${endMonth}`;
    }
  };

  const getFileIcon = (file, src) => {
    // Implement logic to determine the file type and return the appropriate icon
    // For simplicity, I'm using a generic icon for demonstration purposes
    if (file === "jpg" || file === "png" || file === "img") {
      return <img src={src} alt="File Icon" />;
    } else {
      return <FileIcon extension={file} {...defaultStyles[file]} />;
    }
  };
  //--------------------------------------

  // Column defs
  const leftColumns = [...]


 

  //------------------------------------------------

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await getAllItems();
      const responseC = await getCompletedAllItems();
      const newData = response.map((res, i) => ({
        id: res.id,
        project: res.project,
        owner: res.owner,
        status: res.status,
        due_date: res.due_date,
        budget: "$" + res.budget,
        files: res.files, // Updated line
        timeline: res.timeline,
        last_updated: res.last_updated,
      }));
      const newDataC = responseC.map((res, i) => ({
        id: res.id,
        project: res.project,
        owner: res.owner,
        status: res.status,
        due_date: res.due_date,
        budget: "$" + res.budget,
        files: res.files, // Updated line
        timeline: res.timeline,
        last_updated: res.last_updated,
      }));
      setData([...newData, aggregatedDataRow]);
      setCompletedData([...newDataC, aggregatedDataRow]);
      // setData(
      //   localStorage.getItem("rowData")
      //     ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rowData"))
      //     : [...newData, aggregatedDataRow]
      // );
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  const onDragStop = useCallback(
    (params) => {
      var nodes = params.nodes;

      if (radioChecked === 0) {
        leftApi.applyTransaction({
          remove: nodes.map(function (node) {
            return node.data;
          }),
        });
      } else if (radioChecked === 1) {
        leftApi.setNodesSelected({ nodes, newValue: false });
      }
    },
    [leftApi, radioChecked]
  );

  const onDragRStop = useCallback(
    (params) => {
      var nodes = params.nodes;

      if (radioChecked === 1) {
        rightApi.applyTransaction({
          remove: nodes.map(function (node) {
            return node.data;
          }),
        });
      } else if (radioChecked === 0) {
        rightApi.setNodesSelected({ nodes, newValue: false });
      }
    },
    [rightApi, radioChecked]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!leftApi || !rightApi) {
      return;
    }
    const dropZoneParams = rightApi.getRowDropZoneParams({ onDragStop });
    const dropZoneRParams = leftApi.getRowDropZoneParams({ onDragRStop });

    leftApi.removeRowDropZone(dropZoneParams);
    leftApi.addRowDropZone(dropZoneParams);
    rightApi.removeRowDropZone(dropZoneRParams);
    rightApi.addRowDropZone(dropZoneRParams);
  }, [leftApi, rightApi, onDragStop, onDragRStop]);

  const getGridWrapper = (id) => (
    <>
      <div class={`lead-heading-btn ${id > 0 ? "leading-grid-margin" : ""}`}>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>
              {" "}
              {id === 0 ? "To-do" : "Completed"}{" "}
              <a href="#">
                {" "}
                <img src={LeadImg} />{" "}
              </a>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="btn-leads-cta-wrap">
              {" "}
              <a href="#">
                {" "}
                <img src={Filter} /> Filters{" "}
              </a>{" "}
              <a href="#">
                {" "}
                <img src={AddBtn} /> Add New{" "}
              </a>{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="leads-table-wrap">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <div
            className="ag-theme-alpine"
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              minWidth: "900px",
            }}
          >
            <AgGridReact
              gridId={id === 0 ? 0 : 1}
              rowData={id === 0 ? data : completedData}
              columnDefs={leftColumns}
              defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
              // getRowId={getRowId}
              onColumnMoved={swapColumnState}
              onDragStarted={(params) => {
                console.log(params);
                setCurrentId(params.api.gos.gridOptions.gridId);
              }}
              rowSelection={"multiple"}
              // suppressMoveWhenRowDragging={id === 0}
              // suppressRowClickSelection={id === 0}
              rowDragManaged={window.innerWidth > 1000 ? true : false}
              rowDragEntireRow={window.innerWidth > 1000 ? true : false}
              animateRows={true}
              domLayout={"autoHeight"}
              onRowDragEnd={(params) => onRowDragEnd(params, id)}
              singleClickEdit={true}
              suppressHorizontalScroll={true}
              overlayLoadingTemplate={
                '<object style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2)" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://ag-grid.com/images/ag-grid-loading-spinner.svg" aria-label="loading"></object>'
              }
              overlayNoRowsTemplate={
                "<span style=\"padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: lightgoldenrodyellow\">This is a custom 'no rows' overlay</span>"
              }
              onGridReady={(params) => gridReady(params, id)}
              onCellValueChanged={(params) =>
                handleCellValueChanged(params, id)
              }
            ></AgGridReact>
            <div className="w-100 add-lead-new">
              <input
                value={user}
                placeholder="+ Add project"
                onKeyDown={(params) => handleKeyDown(params, id)}
                onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <div className={"leads-table-main-wraper"}>
      {getGridWrapper(0)}
      {getGridWrapper(1)}
      <div className="w-100">
        <button
          className="add-more-grp-btn"
          onClick={() => addGroup("New")}
        >
          + Add new group
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Agtable;
```